# AttrributeError in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write an auth bot with selenium, but I got an error that dont let code to be completed! The error is **"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'"**, you can see the code and the error in terminal **below**.

**Code:**
`

```
class LoginBot():

def __init__(self):
    #Excel reading
    wb = load_workbook('seo-fast_profiles.xlsx')
    sheet_ranges = wb['Work']
    self.login = sheet_ranges['A2'].value
    self.email = sheet_ranges['B2'].value
    self.passw = sheet_ranges['C2'].value

    #Optins and UserAgent
    user = UserAgent()

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_argument(user.random)

    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

def close_browser(self):
    self.browser.close()
    self.browser.quit()

def login(self):
    browser = self.browser
    browser.get("https://seo-fast.ru/login")
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))

    username_input = browser.find_element(By.ID, "logusername")
    username_input.clear()
    username_input.send_keys(self.email)

    time.sleep(1)

    username_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(2)

    password_input = browser.find_element(By.ID, "logpassword")
    password_input.send_keys(self.passw)

    time.sleep(5)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(7)

    #cookies
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open(f"{self.login}_cookies", "wb"))

    self.close_browser()

def xpath_exists(self, url):
    browser = self.browser
    try:
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, url)
        exist = True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exist = False
    return exist


bot = LoginBot()
bot.login()
```

`

**Error:**
`File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__ self.service.start() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'`

Can anyone solve it?

Comment: which line of the code raises the error?

Comment: Line: self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the parameter. It should be like below.

```
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

You need to import below library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```